# I was following the outdated tutorial for unity engine and cant get my script do the intended thing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class player_collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public playermovement movement;
    private void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.gameObject.tag == "obstacle")
        {
            GetComponent<playermovement>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically my script and every variable name is correct
but when I hit some obstacle, playermovement does not turn off somehow.
and before you write something like "why you haven't followed the tutorial strictly" its because original script have not worked for me and I have tried to help myself out with comments, but this haven't worked out as well :sademoji:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAB64vfbrhI&index=6&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5QFsefuO2RlAgWEz6EvVi6
and heres the link for the tutorial I was using.
Current version of unity I am using is 2018.3.7f1

I am using Visual Studio for editing scripts.

Comment: Please read the `visual-studio` tag.  It should only be used when your question is *about* VS, not just using VS.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collisionInfo)` is called, and that the tag is correct? And how have you defined `playermovement`?

Comment: If you use `GetComponent` why do you have a public variable? Now you are trying to access a `playermovement` component which is attached to the object which has this script. Try `movement.enabled = false` maybe?

Comment: Dont't use GetComponent in the frequeny called methods

Comment: okay so `getcomponent` was actually bady implemented here and I have finally managed to do it. I do not know what happened really, but recreating both script AND an obstacle object was somehow a way to go. Anyway thank you all for your help

and here is the actual code that is working for me now

`using UnityEngine;

public class player_collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public playermovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: Just a heads up, whever I work with OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter I always refere back to the table here: [link] (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) it's a great resource for checking whether your collision will actually get detected